# Extract data from xml without xpath

Tags: xml, parsing, xmllint

Here is my issue, I'm working on UNIX, I have a xml file contained into a string *foo*:

```
echo $foo
<a> <b> <c> bar </c> </b> </a>
```

I want to get the value *bar*.
I can use *xmllint* but I don't have *--xpath* option.
Not that *foo* is an UNIX variable and not a file.

The unique solution I found is to run:

```
echo $foo | xmllint --shell <(cat) <<<'xpath a/b/c/text()'
```

But it produces a very verbose output:

```
/ > Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  TEXT
    content= bar
/ >
```

I just want to get “bar”.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Out of curiosity: how come you "don't have --xpath option"? Also, can you use something else that does have it?

Comment: I've a very old xmllint version ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replace `xpath` with `cat` as xmlshell-command to invoke.
This should output something like:

```
/ >  -------
 bar
```

The first line is from the prompt of the xmlshell. To get only the last line, use your favorite tool to extract just line 2, like:

```
foo="<a> <b> <c>_ bar _</c> </b> </a>"

echo "cat //c/text()" | xmllint --shell <(echo $foo) | awk 'NR==2'
```

Comment: perfect, that's the command I was searching for, thanks a lot !